# Link my question posted on Stackoverflow about windows phone

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I've a question regarding Windows-Phone-8 App development. I've asked that on stackoverflow. then i come to know about this "windowsphone.stackexchange.com" so do i need to ask again the same question on this forum..? isn't there should be a connection between stackoverflow and other sub-stackexchange site, that all the questions tagged with "`window-phone`" or related tags will shown up here also..!

Answer (score 5):

[Per the help centre](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) questions relating to *development* of Windows Phone apps are generally off-topic here, and should instead be asked on Stack Overflow (as you have).

There is a connection between the sites, both in terms of software, ownership, but also functionally, with moderators (and staff) having the ability to migrate questions to a more relevant site where applicable (so we would migrate questions relating to development issues to Stack Overflow, and in reverse, a question about using the phone may be migrated from Stack Overflow to here); Similarly, where people have asked about Android phones on here, we have migrated them to the site for Android phones, etc.

More generally, There isn't a natural "master-child" relationship, so I don't see a case for all the questions from one appearing on the other, as you would annoy all the developers with questions asking about finding files received in WhatsApp, and annoy all the end users with questions about passing Models between XAML pages - taking it wider, there are many other Stack Exchange sites (just take a look at the footer for some of the main ones), and it wouldn't make much sense to have a question from https://parenting.stackexchange.com/ about using a breast pump appear on any other site.

Instead, the approach taken is to have focused sites that clearly define their remit, and questions beyond that remit are either closed, or migrated to where they should've been asked.